# ProgressBar dentro de un drawable

Tags: android, progressbar

Con la ayuda de un post de un usuario de aquí, de como quitar la pantalla blanca de la *"pre-carga"* antes del `splahScreen`  he resuelto el problema, ahora bien quisiera saber si en este `drawable` se puede integrar un `progressbar`. Les dejo el `drawable` a continuación ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <item android:top="-48dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_momento"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Deseo cambiar un `progresbar` por la **imagen** que esta cargando o en ultimo caso poder asignarle un tamaño a la imagen ¿ alguna idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrar un `ProgressBar` a un drawable no es posible, puedes desplegar la imagen en un `ImageView` y el `ProgressBar` sería una vista que estaría encima del `ImageView`.

En el caso del SplashScreen lo común es crear un tema el cual relacionaras a la actividad:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_momento</item>
   </style>
```

esta Activity cargara un layout, aquí es donde agregarías tu `ProgressBar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ProgressBar>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: SI, lo que he hecho es usar una imagen en la pre-carga del splash en la propiedad android:windowBackground....